# spring maven repository issue (blog references but wanting to use newer version)

Tags: spring, maven

I have created a maven web project using the below site.

```
http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/
```

I have performed all the steps given there and executed a simple hello world program. Now, I have to include spring dependencies into my eclipse web project.

So

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In the dependencies tag, I added the above configuration. Now, it is saying as below:

```
unable to find jars from the repositories (local and as well as remote)
```

It gave suggestion to execute the command:

```
mvn install -artifactid=springframework   (something like this)
```

But when I mentioned version as 2.5.6 it's correctly taken. Is it the problem with the version 3.1.2 being unavailable at maven repository? How do I get the latest versions if maven is not working properly for latest versions?

It also gave me the suggestion to go for manual download and put in local repository.

Comment: See if answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732531/why-is-spring-published-under-two-different-sets-of-artifacts) help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maven coordinates changed over time.

Try:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

OR Try:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I'll just find if there is an all-in-one POM or dependency.  But "spring-full" looks 1.2.x only and "spring" 2.5.x.  CHECKED: Can't find one I've been using separate modules in all projects for sometime (this is better anyway, fine grained dependencies).

The location you can search is at http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/

for 3.1.2 see http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/library/version/detail?name=org.springframework.spring&version=3.1.2.RELEASE&searchType=librariesByName&searchQuery=spring

Spring have changed their repository URL and online locations at least 3 times to my knowledge over the past 4 years.  So I'd look for current information on their website about setting up a Maven `<repositories>` config to obtain their JARs.  Beware of articles with out of date information :(

Also notice the artifactId is different in the 2 example this is another gotcha issue with spring.  The "org.springframework.core" are their EBR and OSGi compliant versions of their software.  The "spring-core" is the older pre-OSGi co-ordinates.  Find what works for you and don't mix them in the same project.  For example I am using "spring-core" because I use 3.2.0.M2 which are Milestone releases.  But the production release EBR co-ordinates are the best to use.

Sorry for so many edits... but it has been a minefield even if you understand the heritage of getting Spring Source software.